# What should the Issuer be set to in SAML request for Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, saml-2.0

I have read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol, but I am not clear what to set the Issuer value to below. Is this something I can grab from Azure portal. I am using a "Non Gallery Application".

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest
xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
ID="id6c1c178c166d486687be4aaf5e482730"
Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2013-03-18T03:28:54.1839884Z"
xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://www.contoso.com</Issuer>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Answer (score 3):

The issuer is your `SAML2` `entityID`

> this is set to the App ID URI that is specified during application
>   registration

so if your app id uri is something like:

```
https://your.app/saml
```

then that's what you set your Issuer to. The `entityID` is not a URL although they usually look like one and opening it in a browser usually downloads the `SAML2` metadata for the entity but it's not essential. The app id uri is just a unique identifier for your app. Your app issues `SAML` `Request` instances using its app id uri as the Issuer

Answer (score 2):

It's what you have configured on the Azure portal for custom SAML e.g.

Identifier (Entity ID)
https://some address